# Unable to Deploy Application Using Active Directory and GPO

Tags: windows-server-2003, group-policy, deployment

I'm unable to deploy an application using Active Directory and GPO, and I can't figure out why the deployment is not taking place. Below are the steps I took; does anyone know what is or could be preventing the deployment?

1. Created an msi package and stored it in a shared folder
2. Created a new policy for an OU; Using "Computer Configuration" > "Software Installation" > "Package"
3. Restarted the target computer (Nothing happens at this point).

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the GPO is not applying to the user or the machine that you want it to apply to. Log into the machine as the user, and use gpresult or the GPMC RSoP wizard to find out if this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to mfinni's answer, you can often find some useful tidbits in the Application log on one of the clients (assuming the group policy applied properly).

Most of the time I see GPO software install issues, it's a permission thing. The computer account needs read access to the share that you're using.

There's also a pretty critical GPO to apply to the clients. Set this to enabled:

> Computer Configuration \ Administrative Templates \ System \ Logon \ Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon

Comment: The app log indicates that the "installation source for this product is not available." I don't understand this error message as the folder is shared with *domain computers and users*, I've also included *authenticated users*. Any ideas what's the problem here?

Comment: It could be that you've done share permissions correctly without doing NTFS permissions correctly. Check out this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278472

Answer (score 0):

The most common problem I've found with deploying software via GPO is with the msi itself. As a test see if you can deploy a commercial application via it's own msi.